# Ionic - Cordova plugin function getting called twice

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am using the camera preview plugin in my Ionic v1 app.

When I click Start Cam, the camera preview starts and When i Tap Swap Cam,
the $scope.swapCam() function gets called twice, i.e I can see console.log('swapping'); printing twice.
Have tested without CameraPreview.switchCamera();, works fine.

Any help appreciated. Thanks

This is my HTML

```
    <ion-view view-title="Dashboard">
  <ion-content class="padding">
      <button ng-click="startCam()">Start Cam</button>
      <button ng-click="swapCam()">Swap Cam</button>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

and this is my Controller

```
    .controller('DashCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.startCam = function(){
    CameraPreview.startCamera({x: 50, y: 50, width: 300, height: 300, toBack: false, previewDrag: true, tapPhoto: true});
  }

  $scope.swapCam = function(){
    console.log('swapping');
    CameraPreview.switchCamera();
  }
})
```

> ionic info:

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.1
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.1

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 6.5.0 
Gulp CLI              : CLI version 3.9.1 Local version 3.9.1


Cordova Platforms : android 6.1.2
Ionic Framework   : ionic1 1.3.4
```

Comment: I have exactly the same problem but on the iOS Side. Did you find a solution for this?